# error NG8001: 'app-horizontal-bar-chart' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, charts, module.exports, ngx

Me podria ayudar alguien a solventar este error?

> error NG8001: 'app-horizontal-bar-chart' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-horizontal-bar-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-horizontal-bar-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**app.module.ts**- Modulo padre

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { VoteComponent } from './pages/vote/vote.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    VoteComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**components.module.ts**- Modulo de componentes- Modulo hijo

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 

import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';

import { HorizontalBarChartComponent } from './horizontal-bar-chart/horizontal-bar-chart.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    HorizontalBarChartComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent,
    HorizontalBarChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgxChartsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

**horizontal-bar-chart.component.html**

```
<div class="chart-container">

<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="results" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
    style="fill: grey">
</ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
```

**horizontal-bar-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-horizontal-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './horizontal-bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./horizontal-bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class HorizontalBarChartComponent {

  results: any[]=[
    {
      "name": "Game 1",
      "value": 25
    },
    {
      "name": "Game 2",
      "value": 37
    },
    {
      "name": "Game 3",
      "value": 42
    }
  ];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = true;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Games';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Votes';
  colorScheme = 'nightLights';

  constructor(){}
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "goty",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

> > Angular CLI: 14.0.7 Node: 16.14.0 Package Manager: npm 8.12.1  OS: linux x64
>
> Angular: 14.2.2 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core,
> forms ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
>
> Package                         Version
> --------------------------------------------------------- @angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.2 @angular-devkit/build-angular
> 14.2.2 @angular-devkit/core            14.2.2 @angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.7 @angular/cli
> 14.0.7 @schematics/angular             14.0.7 rxjs                            7.5.6 typescript                      4.7.4

Comment: Faltaría ver el package.json :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Ahi va el package.json. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.